# Buddypress redirection to user profile page

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, buddypress

I'm trying to redirect to the user profile page after login un Buddypress. I use this code but it omits the username from the URL for redirection. what do I do?

```
function custom_login_redirect_to($user_login, $user) {
        bp_core_redirect( get_option('siteurl') ."/profile/" . bp_core_get_user_displayname( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) ."/profile/" );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'custom_login_redirect_to', 10, 2);
```

This is what is returned in the URL
`https://mywebsite/profile/profile` instead of `https://mywebsite/profile/username/profile`

Answer (score 1):

This approach is more portable:

```
bp_core_redirect( bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->id ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I was not getting the current user that's why it's failing. 
The code that works.

```
function custom_login_redirect_to($user_login, $user) {
    $username = bp_core_get_username( $user->id );
    bp_core_redirect( get_option('siteurl') ."/profile/" . $username ."/profile/" );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'custom_login_redirect_to', 10, 2);
```